# Django - select all model objects that are in list

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class SupplierOffer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

And from the outer API I got a list of codebrands:

```
api_list = [CodeBrand(code=u'N00105004004', brand=u'NOVONOL'), CodeBrand(code=u'N00105004004', brand=u'Preston')]
```

I want to filter all my supplier offers that match API list items, like this:

```
result = []
for item in api_list:
    result.extend(list(SupplierOffer.objects.filter(code=item.code, brand=item.brand)))
```

It is not the best solution, because it makes 1 db query per item in api_list.

How can I filter offers in 1 db query?

Comment: Normalize your model and use simple pk__in filters.

Comment: @IvanStarostin He wants to query `SupplierOffer` that matches both fields at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Q` queries ([more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)):

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = Q()
for item in api_list:
    query |= (Q(code=item.code) & Q(brand=item.brand))

SupplierOffer.objects.filter(query)
```

You will have a single DB request.

Comment: You meant `
SupplierOffer.objects.filter(query)`  in the last line?

Comment: Yes, only one query is performed in the above code.